# Error with newer Kismet but works with older Kismet

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, utf-8, kismet-wireless

I have a Python script that pulls data from a generated .kismet file so that the information is presented in a summarised format. This file is generated when you stop running Kismet and is a SQLite database underneath. When I run my Python script on a file generated on newer versions of Kismet I get errors, whereas an older version works fine. I updated all other libraries and software too. My Python script makes use of the [Kismetdb Python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/kismetdb/).

I was using **SQLite 3027002** and the one I’m using now is **SQLite 3038002**. I tested both with the new version of Kismet and it made no difference. My original Python version was **Python 3.7.3** and new one is **Python 3.9.2**. I ran my script with both on the new Kismet version and got the same errors.

The Kismet I’m using is **2022-01-R3** and the one before was **2020-12-R3**. [Changelog](https://www.kismetwireless.net/year-archive/) didn’t give an answer. The newer Kismet uses database **version 8** whereas the older is using **version 6** and [according to this](https://www.kismetwireless.net/docs/devel/kismetdb/) **version 8** introduces the **hash** and **packetid** attributes to the **packets** table within generated Kismet file.

When I call `get_all()` the error occurs. When I run this with the old Kismet version `print(KIS_DEVICES.get_all(**query_args))` outputs all devices, which corresponds to the **devices** table in the generated Kismet SQLite file (too long to show). That’s what I’m trying to do but with the new Kismet version that uses kismetdb **version 8**:

```
import json, sys, kismetdb
from datetime import datetime

# Check if KismetDB is Specified as an Argument
if not len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print("[!] No KismetDB Specified")
    sys.exit(0)

# Set Input and Output Files
KIS_IN = sys.argv[1]
KIS_OUT = "%ssummary" % (KIS_IN[:-6])

query_args = {}
# Get Kismet Devices from DB
KIS_DEVICES = kismetdb.Devices(KIS_IN)
print(KIS_DEVICES.get_all(**query_args))

KIS_DB = [row["device"] for row in KIS_DEVICES.get_all(**query_args)]

sys.exit(0)
```

The error with the newer Kismet version:

```
sudo python3 KismetDB_to_Summary\ copy.py new\ pi\ build/Kismet-20220411-23-01-06-1.kismet 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Apolloo /KismetDB_to_Summary copy.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(KIS_DEVICES.get_all(**query_args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kismetdb/base_interface.py", line 155, in get_all
    return self.get_rows(self.column_names, sql, replacements)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kismetdb/base_interface.py", line 325, in get_rows
    for row in cur.fetchall():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kismetdb/utility.py", line 473, in device_field_parser
    retval = json.dumps(json.loads(device))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 1286: invalid start byte
```

I want to use a newer version of Kismet but still be able to extract and filter the generated SQLite data into my summary output.

Comment: It's actually the json module that is failing and it's because it can't decode the contents of the file.  Kismet_devices.get_all is trying to load some json data but can't becuase it's not the proper encoding.  What operating system are you user?

Comment: @alexpdev raspberry pi os, but I've also tested it on my mac.

Comment: It seems at least one row in the devices table has a corrupt `device` column; you can try opening the database in the sqlite shell and  running  `SELECT devkey, device FROM devices` and inspecting the values to see if any look wrong, and manually correcting them.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I can have a look at that, but what is the devkey?

Comment: No idea, probably just a device identifier maybe.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I had a look with DB Browser for SQLite but I wasn't really sure what I was looking for and there were around 2000 entries which made spotting anything very difficult. I wouldn't even know where to look for byte 0Xf5 either.